# flask jinja2 insert content of css file inline

Tags: flask, jinja2

I have  a flask project in which one of the pages needs to be self contained. 
I have a separate file whose content I need to insert into the html page's head.

What's the easiest way to do it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Simply use the [`include`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#include) statement to include the contents:

```
<style type="text/css">
{% include "your.css" %}
</style>
```

Comment: Note that the path is relative from whatever folder is specified to be the template dir (typically, just "templates/"), meaning that if you're in a subfolder, you would need to `include` with the subfolder path.  e.g. to include "about/hours.html" in "about/contact.html", the include would be `{% include "about/hours.html" %}`